# C# async + metro mahapp progress ring

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mahapps.metro

I need progress ring in my application and async because GUI freezes.
I tried different settings async/wait/task/task.run but GUI still frozen and ring not showing up and WaitRing.IsActive in Main and CS.
Yes, I know ping is fast but when address IP is offline, GUI frozen for 4-5s.
It is easier to apply async/await when method is in MainForm.  have a problem with doing this from Class and when message box from mahapp need await.

**XAML:**

```
<Controls:ProgressRing x:Name="WaitRing" IsActive="False" Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
```

**CS:**

public class DrukarkaPing
{
    public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IP { get; set; }

```
public async Task CheckPing(TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IP)
{

    try
    {
        if (TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Text == "" || TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Text == " ")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Ping PingZapytanie = new Ping();
            PingReply PingOdp = PingZapytanie.Send(TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Text);

            if (PingOdp.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else
            {
            TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (window != null)
            await window.ShowMessageAsync("Błąd!", e.Message);
        return;
    }

}
```

**Main:**

```
private async void Button_Drukarki_Sprawdz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WaitRing.IsActive = true;

    TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text = string.Join("", TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    Drukowanie.Drukarka Sprawdz = new Drukowanie.Drukarka(TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text);
    await Sprawdz.CheckCSV(TextBox_Drukarki_IP, TextBox_Drukarki_NS, TextBox_Drukarki_Salon, TextBox_Drukarki_Terminal, TextBox_Drukarki_Status, TextBox_Drukarki_Serwer,
    TextBox_Drukarki_Model, TextBox_Drukarki_Podlaczenie, TextBox_Drukarki_Lokalizacja);

    DrukarkaPing Sprawdznext = new DrukarkaPing();
    await Sprawdznext.CheckPing(TextBox_Drukarki_IP);

    WaitRing.IsActive = false;
}
```

**SecondCS:**

```
   class Drukarka
    {
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IP { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_NS { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Salon { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Terminal { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Status { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Serwer { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Model { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Podlaczenie { get; set; }
        public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Lokalizacja { get; set; }

        public async Task CheckCSV(TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS, TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IP, TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_NS, TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Salon, TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Terminal, TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Status,
            TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Serwer, TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Model, TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Podlaczenie, TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_Lokalizacja)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text == "" || TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text == " "))
                {
                    var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (window != null)
                        await window.ShowMessageAsync("Błąd!", "Podaj numer seryjny!");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text = string.Join("", TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

                    Color Kolor = Color.FromRgb(37, 37, 37);
                    Color Kolor2 = Color.FromRgb(255, 160, 0);

                    TextBox_Drukarki_Terminal.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Kolor);
                    TextBox_Drukarki_Lokalizacja.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Kolor);
                    TextBox_Drukarki_Serwer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Kolor);
                    TextBox_Drukarki_Salon.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Kolor);
                    TextBox_Drukarki_Podlaczenie.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Kolor);
                    TextBox_Drukarki_Status.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Kolor);

                    //TextFieldParser sprawdz = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\Przemysław\OneDrive\Programowanie\wykaz_druk.csv");
                    TextFieldParser sprawdz = new TextFieldParser(@"\\DSB192\Aplikacja_PrintFix$\Raporty\wykaz_druk.csv");
                    string currentLine;
                    sprawdz.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                    sprawdz.Delimiters = new string[] { ";" };
                    sprawdz.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
                    bool czyjest = false;

                    do
                    {
                        currentLine = sprawdz.ReadLine();
                        if (currentLine != null)
                        {
                            string file = currentLine;

                            string STATUS = file.Split(';')[0].Trim();
                            string MODEL = file.Split(';')[1].Trim();
                            string NS = file.Split(';')[2].Trim();
                            string IPD = file.Split(';')[3].Trim();
                            string SERWER = file.Split(';')[4].Trim();
                            //string ??? = file.Split(';')[5].Trim(); kolejka
                            string UDZIAL = file.Split(';')[6].Trim();
                            string LOKAL = file.Split(';')[7].Trim();
                            string SALON = file.Split(';')[8].Trim();
                            //string ??? = file.Split(';')[9].Trim(); lastcom
                            string PODLACZ = file.Split(';')[10].Trim();

                            if (IPD == TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text || NS == TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text)
                            {
                                czyjest = true;
\\ALOT CODE WITH FORWARDING TO TEXT.BOXES and few await window.ShowMessageAsync

                            }
                        }
                    } while (currentLine != null);

                    if (czyjest == false)
                    {
                        var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
                        if (window != null)
                            await window.ShowMessageAsync("Błąd!", "Błędny numer seryjny!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (window != null)
                    await window.ShowMessageAsync("Błąd!", "Błąd pobierania danych.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `var t = TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Text; var PingOdp = await Task.Run(() => PingZapytanie.Send(t));` It is important to get the `Text` property value outside the Task action.

Comment: If the GUI freezes a Progress Ring is not helping (because as you said the GUI is frozen). The main Problem is that your Sprawdz.CheckCSV is probably doing havy work on your UI Thread.Can you show what the Method does?

Comment: Also the whole TRY Block of your CheckPing method is not ASYNC.

Comment: @Clemens Don't work.

Comment: @Console I added second CS with CheckCSV in post. Oh and now showed up progress ring but after freeze.

Comment: "Don't work" isn't a very precise problem statement. Find out where exactly it is blocking. Move that part into a Task.Run call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood the concepts behind async and await.

The code you execute is not executed asynchron because it is not packed in a Task.
The CheckPing Method should look like this if you want the PING to be running in Background.

```
public async Task CheckPing(TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IP)
{
    try
    {
        var text = TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Text; // get TextBox.Text in UI thread

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            //Now the Ping.Send is running in Background
            PingReply PingOdp = await Task.Run(() => 
            {
                 Ping PingZapytanie = new Ping();
                 return PingZapytanie.Send(text);
            });

            //This code is running on the UI Thread again (because you access a FrameworkElement)
            if (PingOdp.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (window != null)
            await window.ShowMessageAsync("Błąd!", e.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

You should [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) to get some information about the concept

Comment: Yes. I have problem with understanding Async/Wait :( I will check this link.
But 
return PingZapytanie.Send(TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Text);
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Comment: @Hoshie Clemes fixed my bug concerning the UI Thread.. You are mixing UI and Logic a lot. I would recommend you invest some time in learning MVVM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx.

Comment: Clemens - I guess I didn't understand your previous comment and it didn't work.
@ Console it's now ok. I will check your links. :)